# How can i remove the rectangle in android?

Tags: android

When I try to remove the rectangle created...

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     x = event.getX();
     y = event.getY(); 
     if (inside(mx, my)) { }  
     for (int i = 0; i < listRect.size(); i++) { 
         if (listRect.get(i).inside(mx, my))  { 
               index = i; 
         } 
     } 
        Rectangle r = listRect.get(index);
        frame.removeView(r); 
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
2064-2064/com.shema.example.schema E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
2064-2064/com.shema.example.schema E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2064-2064/com.shema.example.schema E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
            at com.shema.example.schema.Main.onTouchEventMoveRectangle(Main.java:214)
            at com.shema.example.schema.Main.onTouchEvent(Main.java:95)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
```

Comment: why haven't you edited the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should also remove the rectangle in the list.

```
Rectangle r = listRect.get(index);
frame.removeView(r);
listRect.remove(index);
```

Or you can delete the rectangle in the list and redraw your canvas (I guess it's a canvas)

```
 listRect.remove(index);
 frame.invalidate();
```